# construct an array with key value pairs using a given object with key value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a data object like this :

```
{ '108': '4',
  '1001': '4',
  '1027': '1',
  '1128': '2',
  '1284': '1',
  '1300': '4',
  '1313': '4',
  '1327': '2',
  '1334': '1',
  '1351': '4',
  '1356': '1' }
```

Here for eg '108' is the key and '4' is the value.

I have declared an array called valuearray;

Now I want to put the data object into the extarray.

What i have done :

```
        var x;
        var count = 0;
        for(x in data){
            extarray[count] = data[x];
            count++;
        }
```

x refers to the keys in data object
I have used the count variable to set index in extarray.

when i do console.log(extarray) it gives me the output as

```
[ '4',
  '4',
  '1',
  '2',
  '1',
  '4',
  '4',
  '2']
```

but my expected output for console.log(extarray) is :

```
      ['108': '4',
      '1001': '4',
      '1027': '1',
      '1128': '2',
      '1284': '1',
      '1300': '4']
```

where 108 is the key and 4 is the value in reference to the above expected array. if i do it like extarray[x] then it doesnt work as expected.

my basic requirement is that the key and value in the data object and the extarray should be same
If I do extarray[1001] then the output should come as 4 (refer the data object)
How do I do it?

Comment: Your expected output array structure is incorrect

Comment: You already have an object with these keys and values. Arrays don't (normally) have keys and values.

Comment: The expected output you provided is not valid. perhaps you want an **array of objects**? http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/7co8L09r/

Comment: i want it such that if i do extarray['1001'] the output should be 4 (refer the data object)

Comment: But @pravinnavle you already have that in the object.

Comment: @pravinnavle you already have that, no need to do anything at all.

Comment: i have a requirement where I cant use the data object. that's why I'm constructing another array called extarray

Comment: @pravinnavle you already have in your required format.

Comment: Then you need to provide valid JS so we can understand it. This isn't valid javascript: `['108': '4','1001': '4']` Are you just trying to clone your original object?

Comment: @pravinnavle what is the exact requirement? being unable to use Objects? if so, you just **can't** do that with regular arrays, please clarify the requirements and **eventual limitations**.

Comment: ok how can I put the data object into the extarray such the extarray[1001]  will give the result as 4 ? my basic requirement is that the key and value in the data object and the extarray should be same

Comment: Instead of `extarray[count] = data[x]` you do `extarray[x] = data[x]`. But I really fail to see the point in doing so.

Comment: @pravinnavle extarray just **can't** be an array if you need to access keys through strings (cool fact: it can be, but is it worth it?). If you can access key through numbers, you can think about the solution provided below, where you create a sparse array. However, I don't see why there is any sort of limitation about **not** using a regular object, as it will also be faster in the enumeration.

Comment: @deceze I did exactly as you have mentioned but that returned an array with around 8000 objects. The object count should have been around 123

Comment: Yes, if you have an index `8000`, then the array length is `8000`, even if most of those values are `undefined`. `let arr = []; arr[8000] = 'foo'; console.log(arr.length); // 8001`

Comment: guys please take a look at my new [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894075/angularjs-filter-based-on-matching-values-in-nested-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [sparse array](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html) from the object, using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

To find the length of the new array, get the keys of the object with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and find the maximum by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

```js
const obj = {"108":"4","1001":"4","1027":"1","1128":"2","1284":"1","1300":"4","1313":"4","1327":"2","1334":"1","1351":"4","1356":"1"};
  
const arr = Array.from({ ...obj, length: Math.max(...Object.keys(obj)) });

console.log(arr[1001]); // 4
console.log(arr['1027']); // 1

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Seems like he needs to access keys using strings rather than number (not exactly clear, but he is mentioning string keys). Clever approach though.

Comment: Thanks. He can access the items with strings as well (see updated example).

Comment: Thanks. let me try this

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked for me

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @OriDrori please take a look at my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894075/angularjs-filter-based-on-matching-values-in-nested-array)